# I/flutter (18793): PlatformException(network_error, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 7: , null, null)

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm working on authentication part of my flutter project. **I want to carryout out exception handling for login when the phone is not connected to internet.** The app has 3 auth providers: Phone, GoogleSignIn, and email. The error message is displayed properly for phone signin and email sigin using FirebaseException, which displays the error message. **But for GoogleSignIn, if the device is not connected to the internet the code fails at** :

```
final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
```

Since the execution fails at this point I think FirebaseAuthException doesnt work as it is not supported in googleSignIn.

For which FirebaseAuthException doesnt work, but only "Exception" works.
And i dont get the proper error message using Exception in an alert Dialog.

**Code for Email SignIn with exception handling.**

```
Future<void> signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      String email,
      String password,
      void Function(FirebaseAuthException e) errorCallback,
      ) async {
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      );
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      errorCallback(e);
    }
  }
```

**Error Dialog which gets called in errorCallback(e)**

```
void _showErrorDialog(BuildContext context, String title, Exception e) {
    showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text(
            title,
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
          ),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ListBody(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  '${(e as dynamic).message}',
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: const Text('OK',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
            ),)
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Exception handling using FirebaseAuthException for email

[Exception handling using FirebaseAuthException for email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmmNF.jpg)

---

Google SignIn

```
Future<void> signInWithGoogle (
      void Function(Exception e) errorCallback,
      ) async {
    try{
      final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication? googleAuth = await googleUser!.authentication;
      final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth!.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
      );
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
    }
    on Exception catch (e) {
      print(e);
      errorCallback(e);
    }
  }
```

[Exception handling for google login using Exception instead of FirebaseAuthException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXbdE.jpg)

Error printed in console
I/flutter ( 4383): PlatformException(network_error,com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 7: , null, null)

**P.S I just want the proper network error to be displayed in the alert dialog and not " com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 7"**

Answer (score 2):

#### Update

Since `FirebaseAuthException` isn't called as execution fails at `GoogleSignIn`, `FirebaseAuthException` cannot be used.

While the error printed in log is a `PlatformException`, we can use `PlatformException` instead of `Exception` in the try catch block and check the **error code since its supported by `PlatformException`**.

The error code can be compared with `GoogleSignIn.kNetworkError` and `GoogleSignIn.kSignInFailedError`.

```
Future<void> signInWithGoogle (
    void Function(String errorMessage) errorCallback,
) async {
    try {
        final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
        final GoogleSignInAuthentication? googleAuth = await googleUser!.authentication;
        final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
            accessToken: googleAuth!.accessToken,
            idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
        );
        await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
    }
    on PlatformException catch (e) {
        if (e.code == GoogleSignIn.kNetworkError) {
            String errorMessage = "A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.";
            errorCallback(errorMessage);
        } else {
            String errorMessage = "Something went wrong.";
            errorCallback(errorMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLHOF.jpg)